# Search in Windows 7 does not find items by name

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I've got a small problem with the Windows 7 search:
I want to search my image folders files by name. It's not in the default location under C:\Users, but it was moved properly. I've looked it up in the search settings, it should be indexed properly (the checkbox for the My Pictures folder is checked) but when I search for files with names I know are in that folder, no result comes up. Other libraries, such as Music or Personal files are indexed correctly. Image files are set in the file extensions searched (e.g. jpeg, jpg, ...). I've even tried rebuilding the search index, but nothing helped, that folder is not searched.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Does the window show that everything is indexed? Have you checked the permissions of the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TomWij only commented and did not answer, I cannot accept it as an answer, so thanks to him this worked :-/

I have no idea why, but it seems somehow permission for these folders for the account "SYSTEM" was taken from the folders that could not be searched. It didn't occur to me to be a permission problem as I had no problem accessing them. The Windows Search service seems to be started as SYSTEM user, so it lacked exactly those permissions.